# Object.entries return an empty Array

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, e-commerce, mern

I am following a MERN ecommerce tutorial which I stuck at the point where we want to filter the product by color & size

here is Mongo model

```
   const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    categories: {
      type: Array,
    },
    size: {
      type: Array,
    },
    color: {
      type: Array,
    },
    price: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    countInStock: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)
```

This is get allProduct endpoint (express.js backend)

```
 const getAllProducts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  //We need to give user query functionality
  const qNew = req.query.new //we find by latest product
  const qCategory = req.query.category //we can find by category
  try {
    let products
    if (qNew) {
      products = await Product.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 }).limit(1)
    } else if (qCategory) {
      products = await Product.find({
        categories: {
          $in: [qCategory], //inside the categories Array
        },
      })
    } else {
      products = await Product.find({})
    }

    res.status(200).json(products)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(404)
    throw new Error('No User Found')
  }
})
```

This what we set the route in App.jsx

```
<Route path="/products/:category" element={<ProductList/>}></Route>
```

In the productList we create filter keyword and pass them as props to Product (React frontend)

```
    const ProductList = () => {
  const location = useLocation()
const category = location.pathname.split("/")[2]//get the category key word

const [filters,setFilter] = useState({})
//when change color or size it will change state
const [sort,setSort] = useState("newest")

const handleFilter = (e) =>{
  const value = e.target.value;//value is whatever we enter 
  //whether it's color or size it will change state
  setFilter({
    ...filters,//when I select color and size togather both will inside same Array 
[e.target.name]:value,//if we select red from option the filter value is red, if select L size from size option then filter value is L
  })
}

    return (
        <Container>
            <Navbar/>
            <Announcement/>
             <Title>Dresses</Title>
            <FilterContainer>
                <Filter>
                    <FilterText>Filter Products:</FilterText>
            <Select name="color" onChange={handleFilter}>
            <Option disabled >
              Color
            </Option>
            <Option>white</Option>
            <Option>black</Option>
            <Option>red</Option>
            <Option>blue</Option>
            <Option>yellow</Option>
            <Option>green</Option>
          </Select>
          <Select name="size" onChange={handleFilter}>
            <Option disabled >
              Size
            </Option>
            <Option>XS</Option>
            <Option>S</Option>
            <Option>M</Option>
            <Option>L</Option>
            <Option>XL</Option>
          </Select >
                </Filter>
                <Filter>
                <FilterText>Filter Products:</FilterText>
            <Select onChange={(e) =>setSort(e.target.value)}>
            <Option value="Newest">Newest</Option>
            <Option value="asc">Price (asc)</Option>
            <Option value="desc">Price (desc)</Option>
          </Select>
                </Filter>
            </FilterContainer>
            <Products category={category} filters={filters} sort={sort}/>
            {/* category key word / filter keyword size & color / sort keyword Newst */}
            <Footer/>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

And we make HTTP request in Product page, I pretty sure there have an object return back from endpoint inside res.data and updated in products(useState) but after the Object.entries filtering logic all it return was empty Array in filteredProducts(useState)

```
    const Products = ({category,filters,sort}) => {
const [products,setProducts] = useState([]);
const [filteredProducts,setFilteredProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() =>{//category key word
const getProducts = async ()=>{
    try{
    const res = await axios.get(category ? `http://localhost:5000/api/products?category=${category}` : "http://localhost:5000/api/products")
    setProducts(res.data)//data won't go in state imediately

    }catch(err)
    {
console.log(err)
    }
}
getProducts()
//untill here the products still have the data inside
},[category,setProducts])

useEffect(() =>{
category && setFilteredProducts(
    products.filter((item) =>
    Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) =>
      item[key].includes(value)
    )
  )
    
)
},[category,products,filters,setFilteredProducts])


    return (
        <Container>

            {category ?
            filteredProducts.map((item) =>
            <Product item={item} key={item._id} />) :
            products
            .slice(0,8)
            .map((item) => <Product item={item}/>)
            //whenever you use map you need to indicate unique key
           
    }
        </Container>
    )
}
```

Anyone can help me with this issue ? I really want to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!! I didn't set the corresponding category in my MongoDB so that's why when it goes to filtering logic it couldn't find the data to send back to frontend